# Problems with theming a grid

Tags: views, theming

I am having problems trying to control the layout and fields together in a grid style of a view.
On the internet I saw several tutorials about how to theme views, and they suggest using functions in template.php, or using view template files. I cannot find a tutorial that helps me.

Specifically, when I use a template file, I cannot control the disposition of fields (controlling the disposition of each field; controlling the fields altogether; adding conditionals; adding classes; trying to use "views-view--," "views-view-field--," "views-view-fields--," or "views-view-grid--"), and when I use a function in template.php, I cannot get the variables/values of fields.

I must say that I know how to include a custom design using the Views module interface, to control the design per fields (or controling all fields of each item, if I include the design and fields in the last field). But I want to do this using some external way to custom display in a **centralized way** (also to not allow to change the design from the web interface, and to have the control in a files, not in the database).

When I say **a centralized way**, I mean, using a file or files to control the disposition of each field, control fields together, add conditionals, add classes, add functions, (such as a theme in Drupal).

I am using Drupal 6 and Views 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in views-view-grid--viewname.tpl.php, with `print_r($variables)`, you will find the whole values in the 'view' array (is a very huge output, so I recomend only pull 1 item in this test).

here you will discover that '`result`' carry the `stdClass Object` with the fields of views (not it all, seems that the images are not there), to print this you can use:

```
print_r($variables['view']->result);
```

with the id of the values, you can use these values for example, show a node title:

```
echo $variables['view']->result[$i]->node_title;
```

or you can use the id of the node to get, for example, images from nodes (seems that the images are not in `result`).

```
$nIdItem = $variables['view']->result[$i]->nid;
$node = node_load($nIdItem);
echo "<img src='/".$node->field_image[0]['filepath']."'>";
```

so with this way is possible to control each field, set of fields, and/or add conditions, functions.

I do not know the performance or security implications of using this way, this may be a new question.